# Package Dependencies are Broken?

Tags: 13.04, updates, package-management

I'm not able to install VLC Media Player, or even update my computer. I get

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Then I click More Details and get

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) but 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 6:0.8.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.11-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.3 is to be installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.3 is to be installed
Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.7.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

When I update the system using Terminal, I get

```
Fetched 817 kB in 29s (27.7 kB/s)
N: Ignoring file 'duinsoft.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: GPG error: http://www.duinsoft.nl debs Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E18CE6625CB26B26
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/...amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/...-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Sources List

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/noobslab-conky/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/noobslab-conky/ubuntu precise main
```

AFTER FOLLOWING INSTRUCTION

```
W: GPG error: http://www.duinsoft.nl debs Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E18CE6625CB26B26
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
cyberproxy@Paradox:~$  sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  efibootmgr grub-efi-amd64-bin kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'duinsoft.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: When you say "when I update the system" you mean `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Yes. Nor can I install VLC Media Player, etc.

Comment: Please provide this file: /etc/apt/sources.list

You can use `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to do this.

Comment: Edited the original question and submitted list.

Comment: Answer edited, it didn't work, still.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your apt list, and make a new one:

Delete the old list:
`sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists && sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`

Generate a new one:
`sudo apt-get update`

Now you should be able to install the missing dependencies by running:
`sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I still got an error at the end

Comment: Yep, but you should now be able to install VLC. Just try `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: Will I be able to get updates from Ubuntu Software Updater? Or sudo apt-get update?

Comment: I tried updating, but it told me "Failed to download respiratory information."

Comment: This file "duinsoft.listsudo" has a wrong name, rename it into "duinsoft.list". You can do this running: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/duinsoft.listsudo /etc/apt/sources.list.d/duinsoft.list`.

Now run `sudo apt-get update` again . Anyway update does NOT update your system, it just re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. To "update your system" you have to run: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help today! I really appreciate it. I tried your solution and got [W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.]

Comment: They're just warnings, they won't cause any trouble. You're having these W because you're using screenlets PPA which is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 raring. If you don't want to see these warning anymore you have to remove those PPAs. If you want, you can do this by installing ppa-purge. You can install it running: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` and then `sudo ppa-purge ppa:screenlets/ppa`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, but Software Updater won't even download repositories, as it quotes. So just ignore it, and in the future it'll get them? Just not for Screenlets I assume.

Comment: You can remove that PPA if you want as I wrote before. Software Updater won't download packages from that PPA because, but will download from the others. Anyway if you are not using screenlets, remove that ppa.